# comment causes [package error]

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I want to export an org file containing a tikz diagram to pdf.
I've read [the manual](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html). 
This is the most minimal example I could come up with:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((latex . t)))
  (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
#+end_src

#+header: :file (by-backend (html "tree.svg") (t 'nil))
#+header: :imagemagick
#+header: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))
#+begin_src latex
  \begin{tikzpicture} %foo
    \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (1);
    %\draw (ba) circle (1);  
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

To execute I put the cursor in the elisp block and do `C-c C-c`, then `M-x org-latex-export-to-pdf`

This yields:

> Process completed with errors: [package error]

Interestingly it works when I remove just one of the 2 comments (or replace `ba` by `0,0`)

Upon doing `M-x org-latex-export-to-latex` I can see that the code block evaluates to

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \%foo
  \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (1);
  \%\draw (ba) circle (1);    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The comments aren't ignored but the `%` are escaped!  (And the package error is probably how latex deals with unknown tokens `foo` and `ba`)

How can I keep the comments in my code and still compile?

Org-mode version 8.2.10
GNU Emacs 25.2.2

**Progress:**
jagrg is correct I don't get the error with `emacs -Q`.
I have now 2 types of errors:

```
emacs -Q --load debug_init
```

1) With `debug_init` being either of the following files:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/mu4e")
(require 'mu4e)
--- or ---
;;(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/mu4e")
(require 'mu4e)
```

results in `Process completed with errors: [package error]`
and If I remove `%foo` it compiles.
(I can also just fix up the generated `.tex` file)

2) with `emacs -Q` or either of the following init files:

```
(require 'package)
;;(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/mu4e")
;;(require 'mu4e)
--- or ---
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/mu4e")
;;(require 'mu4e)
```

I get `by-backend: Symbol’s function definition is void: case`

**Update 2**
`Symbol’s function definition is void` is solved, thanks jagrg!

current setup:

myinit:

```
(require 'cl-lib)                                                                                           
(org-babel-do-load-languages                                                                                
 'org-babel-load-languages '((latex . t)))                                                                  
(setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")                                                                  
(defmacro by-backend (&rest body)                                                                         
 `(cl-case (if (boundp 'backend) 
               (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
```

main.org:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+header: :file (by-backend (html "tree.svg") (t 'nil))
#+header: :imagemagick
#+header: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))
#+begin_src latex
  \begin{tikzpicture} %foo
    \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (1);
    %\draw (ba) circle (1);  
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

open with `emacs -Q --load myinit main.org` then type `M-x -l-pd`
resulting in `Process completed with errors: [package error]`

**Update 3**
changing "raw" to "results" does the trick.

Comment: I have no idea why mu4e is triggering the error. To fix the void case symbol you might have to require cl.el.

Comment: I put `(require 'cl)` as first line of my elisp block now all examples give package error.

Comment: Try changing "raw" to "results" and see if that works for you. With the "raw" argument the result is not wrapped inside a block, and therefore the exporter has no way of knowing that the code should export to latex.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I cannot reproduce your problem. The %foo comment should not be escaped so there's definitely something wrong, either with your configuration or a bug with your version of Org. I would try with emacs -Q first and if it still fails I would try upgrading Org. You could also check for errors in the compilation buffer.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my answer